# why oxidation states of suphur atoms of Disuphur-monoxide is +2 and 0?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, oxidation-state

[image]

I) According to my logic, sulfur-sulfur linkage (linkage between same atoms) result in no charge separation.So, the oxidation number of the sulfur atom linked to only sulfur should be 0(zero) and other sulfur being +4 as it is connected to 3(more electronegative) oxygen atoms.

Thus, the oxidation number of sulfur atoms should be +4,0.

II)However, [Using X-ray absorption to probe sulfur oxidation states in complex molecules](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S138614259800153X) claims that oxidation states are +6 and -2.

III)Again,[Determination of Changes in Sulfur Oxidation States
in Prostate Cancer Cells](http://przyrbwn.icm.edu.pl/APP/PDF/121/a121z2p71.pdf) proved that that oxidation states are +5,-1.

These three sets of results left thoroughly confused.*Which one of them is correct and why?*

Following the same sequence of logic:
My counter-question for the claims (I) and (II) is 
***"Why the oxidation number of sulfur atoms of Disulfur monoxide is [ +2 and 0 ] instead of [+4 and -2] or [+3 and -1] ?"***

[image: Disulfur monoxide]

Comment: Related: [Oxidation states of the sulfur atoms in the thiosulfate ion](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/24928/16683)

Comment: orthocresol .Sir, I went to the link you have sent me but it doesn't answer my question and   specifically my counter question . What is the absolute answer of the oxidation states of sulphur?

Comment: Is it +6 and -2 or +5 and -1?

Comment: There is no absolute answer. Oxidation states are human invention and not facts of nature.

Comment: Couldn't you just treat terminal S as [non-innocent ligand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-innocent_ligand) and give us a break?

Comment: Ivan Neretin. Sir , I know chemistry is a subject based on more or less hypothetical things such as electrons which nobody has seen but has great deal to be talked about.      Can  you please help me out from the dilemma of oxidation states?

Comment: Milthoron. Sir can you please explain in detail.