How do you determine the oxidation states of elements in KSCN (potassium thiocyanate)?
How would one determine oxidation grades in KSCN (potassium thiocyanate)?
(Besides potassium which is absolutely obvious.)
Believe me, for me personally this question is extremely hard.
Of course, I tried googling.
Also, I have asked this question on my site and I got a different answer.
So, essentially, I have received two different answers, two different opinions.
Which one of them is correct (or maybe both are correct? I don't quite believe in this last option though).
K+1, S–2, C+4, N–3.
K+1, S–1, C+3, N–3.
Those are my two options. I mainly hesitate between them. I have heard that carbon in organic compounds can have any grade of oxidation including zero.

Rather than link to the videos, show what you believe are the possible oxidation states.

Thanks, @DrMoishePippik, your comment is useful. I suggested two possible variants in bold. If I must delete my links, I can delete them myself.

what procedure would you normally use to assign oxidation states and what is the result when you apply that procedure here?

You do realize that oxidation states are but a human convention, right?

@Andrew, for example, K2Cr2O7. Potassium is always +1. Oxygen is –2 (we don't have fluorine in our chemical compound, and it is not a peroxide). Let us suppose we know nothing about chromium, so let us denote it with x. The sum of all oxidation states must equal zero. Thus: +1 * 2 + 2x – 7 * 2 = 0; 2 + 2x – 14 = 0; 2x = 12; x = +6. As for KSCN, there are more elements (specifically, S and C) for which we don't know anything, so our equation becomes indeterminate (we have more variables than the number of equation is).

You don't know anything about S and C? Really? To find ox. state you need to know full rules - not just a few rules of thumb, but order of priority telling you that if C is bonded with S then effect is just like it was N. At this point, that C is +4 should be obvious, not "extremely hard".

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/69798/an-introduction-to-oxidation-state-oxidation-number https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10944/electronegativity-considerations-in-assigning-oxidation-states

For actually difficult issues with ox. states you need things like non-innocent ligands.

The formal oxidation number evaluation considers the conventional value of electronegativity of C atom, which is slightly lower than for S and significantly lower than for SP hybridized C atom. So then ON(S)=-2, ON(C) is +4. If SP C had been taken instead, it would have been ON(S) is -1, ON(C) is +3.

The best way to calculate the oxidation states is to draw the geometry of the substance as correctly as possible, with visible covalences, and then to transform all covalent bonds into ionic bonds, with a positive charge on the less electronegative side of the bond, and a negative charge on the more electronegative side of the bond. This gives a final charge to each atom, and this charge is the oxidation number.
In the case of KSCN, the  atoms S, C and N are on a line S-C-N, with three covalences between C and N, and a negative charge on S, corresponding to the positive charge of K . When all covalences are replaced by ionic bonds, K has one positive charge, S two negative charges, C four positive charges (because C is the less electronegative atom of the three atoms in SCN) and N has three negative charges. The oxidation numbers are the same as given in your first sequence. They are : K+1, S–2, C+4, N–3.
